# Reproduce predictions of a gbm model fitted by R in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, prediction, gbm

I would like to reproduce the predictions in Excel (VBA) using the objects (imported in Excel) given by a gbm model like "C.splits", "var.levels",... but I don't know which objects to use and how....

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Samantha

Comment: Your best solution might be for one in which R is called from Excel (or vice versa). There are various libraries that have been written (see https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/ ). Beyond that, Excel does have basic linear regression but doesn't have more sophisticated models built-in. VBA is Turing complete, so you can of course *implement* whatever algorithm is implemented in R, though it is likely to be a non-trivial undertaking.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to use R at all so that anyone can use the program (Not all the computers have R). I would like to implement a algorithm to reproduce my GBM models but I don't know how....

Comment: Unless you can find an already existing implementation of gradient boosting in VBA, your options seem to be to either use R or to write hundreds or even thousands of lines of VBA code.  You could delve into the source of the `gbm` package and translate it into VBA. It seems like a major project. It is probably easier to require that the people using your program have R. One idea is to use Microsoft R, which might prove easier to integrate with Excel. It has its own approach to gradient boosting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/scaler-user-guide-boosting

Comment: Thank you. I only want to reproduce the predictions with VBA and not to fit the model. The model is fitted by R and then I save it and import its parameters to Excel to predict.

Comment: It will be very difficult to do that?

Comment: If R does the heavy lifting then it wouldn't be quite so hard to use the results in Excel VBA, though I'm not familiar enough with the details of the `gbm` package to know what would be entailed. It seems like it would still be somewhat involved (if your goal is to reproduce the functionality of `predict.gbm` in VBA). If you are going to use R -- why not let R do just about everything, simply call it from Excel?

Comment: Yes my goal is to reproduce the functionality of predict.gbm in VBA but without using R. I succeed with predict.rf and now I'm trying to do the same with GBM but I don't know exactly how the predictions are built. Thanks for your help.